# ng-hide in angularjs issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework

i want to hide a field if a certain value of select option is selected in my form.i used ng-hide but could not get what i wanted.Initially the field should display and when i choose a certain value from another field ,the field that i want to hide should be hidden.

My code (form)

```
 <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' :submitted && (userForm.productCat.$pristine || thirdPartyForm.productCat.$invalid)}">
                <label  class="labelColor"><h5><b>Product Category</b></h5></label>
                <select id="productCat" name="productCat"  style="margin: auto; width:100%; " ng-model="user.productCat" ng-change="hideFields()" ng-options="cat.name for cat in productCatList"  required>
                    <option value="" selected="selected">--Select Type--</option>
                    <optgroup label="user.productCat.name"></optgroup>

                </select><br>

                <span class="help-inline" ng-show="submitted && (userForm.productCat.$pristine || userForm.productCat.$invalid)" >A Product Category is required.</span>


            </div>


             <!--Call Method-->
            <div ng-hide="true" >
            <div class="form-group " ng-class="{ 'has-error' :submitted && (userForm.Callmethod.$pristine || thirdPartyForm.Callmethod.$invalid) }">
                <label  class="labelColor"><h5><b>Call Method</b></h5></label>
                <select id="Callmethod" name="Callmethod"  style="margin: auto; width:100%; " ng-model="user.Callmethod"   ng-options="call.name for call in callMethodList"   required>
                    <option value="" selected="selected">--Select Type--</option>
                    <optgroup label="user.Callmethod.name"></optgroup>

                </select><br>

                <span class="help-inline" ng-show="submitted && (userForm.Callmethod.$pristine || userForm.Callmethod.$invalid)" >A Call Method is required.</span>


            </div>
            </div>
```

To my select field i have given 2 options as General and ISLAMIC. If i use ISLAMIC my next field should be hidden.

my js

```
  $scope.productCatList = [{"id":"1","name":"General"},{"id":"2","name":"ISLAMIC"}]
                                   //$scope.callMethodList = [{"id":"1","name":"PROFIT RATE"},{"id":"2","name":"PROFIT RATIO"}]
                                   $scope.hideFields = function() {
                                   if($scope.user.productCat.name == "ISLAMIC"){

                                   $scope.true= false;
                                   } 
                                   }
```

This is how i tried to do it but did not work.

Comment: use a different property name than `true`. That is simply asking for problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use `$scope.true` property, it's really confusing because then in `ng-hide="true"` Angular's parser interprets it literally as `true` value which stays true always (however you can make it work even with this unfortunate name using square bracket notation).

Instead call your flag something like `hidden` and in controller handle it this way:

```
$scope.hidden = false;

$scope.hideFields = function() {
    $scope.hidden = $scope.user.productCat.name == "ISLAMIC";
}
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/N53NcCLtKP4qC1p9G1BK?p=preview

Comment: Thank you.your method should work .i used this same code but strangely i did not work.i dont know why